# measuring unix machine responsiveness

Tags: unix, statistics

I am one of the `n` users of a shared unix machine. For reasons unknown, the machine is not "responsive" enough. For example, it is slow on interactive commands, it takes few noticeable moments for any action (e.g. mouse movement, editor (e.g. gvim) keystrokes) to be visible. The problem is, the people supposedly responsible for addressing the issue do not agree that the machine is not responsive. They do some few simple things and say, "It works fine!"

I want to collect some "data" to quantify responsiveness. What can I do?

I can run shell commands like `top` periodically with `cron` and collect statistics, but I am clueless regarding what is a good statistic to go after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `time` command to measure how long it takes to execute a simple command (e.g. ls) in "real" (wall-clock) time.  Also, you could periodically record the statistics from `uptime`, which shows how many tasks are currently being executed. If this number is usually higher than the number of processors available, then you have processes waiting.

Comment: Good ideas -- it might be good to include a few measures of network latency and throughput (ping times, or time to download a small file from a remote server).  A slow network could explain the symptoms @Arun is seeing.

Comment: Thanks. I got it partially -- can you please elaborate on the `uptime` interpretation?

Comment: @Arun: `uptime` shows system load averages over different time averages -- smaller numbers are better. Ideally you never want to see this number larger than 1 (or 2, if you're on a dual core machine).